# window.find working across block elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

window's find method is working across inline element boundaries:

```
Some <em>sample</em> text.
console.log( window.find('le te') );    // true
```

But it doesn't seem to work for block element boundaries:

```
Some <div>sample</div><div>text</div>.
console.log( window.find('le\r\nte') ); // false
```

Did I use the method incorrectly or do I need a workaround here?
My goal is to find 'lete' in the above example in order to manipulate it.
(No RegExp needed - only search for definite strings)

Comment: Are you sure you got that sample text right? As a sidenote `window.find` is not part of any stardard.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.find "DOM Level 0. Not part of any standard."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative to search `textContent` of the document body:

```
Some <div>sample</div><div>text</div>.
console.log(document.body.textContent.search(/le\s*te/)>-1); // true
```

See [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent).

As the comments to your question point out, there is no standard how it should work. If you  remove the `\r` character, this code works in Chrome, but not in FF:

```
Some <div>sample</div><div>text</div>.
console.log( window.find('le\nte') ); // true
```

Comment: I only need it to work in the latest FF. `find` would be great since I could get a range object from it which enables me to manipulate the corresponding part of the DOM. For this reason `textContent` is unsuitable. Im afraid I have to traverse all text nodes :/